# Cannot statically analyse 'require(…, …)' in line 16

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using nextjs.

When importing `markdown-toc` in nextjs I am getting the issue.
`/pages/index.js`

```js
import toc from "markdown-toc";
```

Then I got the below error

```js
./node_modules/markdown-toc/lib/utils.js
Cannot statically analyse 'require(…, …)' in line 16
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When going through the lib code:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies
 */

var diacritics = require('diacritics-map');
var utils = require('lazy-cache')(require);
var fn = require;
require = utils;

/**
 * Lazily required module dependencies
 */

require('concat-stream', 'concat');
```

`require` gets overwritten by the library `utils` assignment (although it seems like a terrible idea).

I don't know what bundler you use, but this is probably the source of the problem as it tries to evaluate the `require` with two parameters, which it cannot do.

I would log a Github ticket to use another identifier than `require` and fix the source of the problem.